# Stuck with null pointer and empty string check

Tags: c, string, nullpointerexception, null, null-pointer

Im new to C and programming. I tried to make an uppercase program but I should do null pointer check and empty string check. How could I continue? i just want to understand this.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

int *toUpper(char *str)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
            str[i] = str[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
     {
         printf(toUpper(argv[i]));
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you, if you don't need format conversion (using conversion specifiers), use `puts()`, instead of `printf()`.

That said, you need to check two things for your `toUpper()` function:

1. You need to check whether the incoming argument is a null pointer or not before accessing. You can check the incoming pointer against `NULL`, like

   ```
   int *toUpper(char *str){
       if (str) {             //makes sure `str` is not a NULL pointer
         // do operation
        }
         // else 
        return NULL;      //indicate error condition
    }
   ```
2. You need to check if the supplied string is not empty. For that, you can check whether the first element is `NUL` or not, using:

   ```
   int *toUpper(char *str){
       if (str) {
          if (str[0] != '\0')     // check the first element
         // do operation
        }
         // else 
        return NULL;      //indicate error condition
    }
   ```

Comment: I think i understood, but how could i integrate to the main, to get the correct uppercase output?

Comment: @GSzab means? What you need to integrate?

Comment: sorry i used wrong words, i'd like to use this toUpper function in main

Comment: @GSzab Yes, that is OK. you can call `toUpper()` from `main()`, inside the for loop, like `char * ret = toUpper(argv[i]); if (ret) puts(ret);`

Comment: for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
            str[i] = str[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
      if (str[i] = ' ') { str[i] = str[i];}

i can do it like this?

Comment: @GSzab not needed, at all, see the first `if` check, if it is a space, it does not undergo the `if` block, retained as-is.